# Language redirection on custom thankyou page using Polylang in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, polylang

In Woocommerce, I am working on my custom thank you page when you finish your order. Everything is done but what I need is to redirect english orders to english language Thank you page and major language to the major Thank you page.

I ve added this code to `functions.php` but its only redirecting to the url which is set. How could I set 2 differend urls for 2 different languages?

Main language: Slovak 
2nd language: English 
Plugin used for translations: Polylang

My code:

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'woo_custom_redirect_after_purchase' );
function woo_custom_redirect_after_purchase() {
    global $wp;

    if ( is_checkout() && !empty( $wp->query_vars['order-received'] ) )
    {
        wp_redirect( '/dakujeme-za-objednavku/' );
        exit;
    }
}
```

And when I use this code it redirects only to url which is not set to en_US (to /vi/cam-on not to thank you when the language is english

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'bbloomer_redirectcustom');
function bbloomer_redirectcustom( $order_id ){

    $order = new WC_Order( $order_id );

    if( get_locale() == 'en_US'){
        $url = get_site_url().'/thank-you';        
    }else{
        $url = get_site_url().'/vi/cam-on';
    }
    if ( $order->status != 'failed' ) {
        wp_redirect($url);
        exit;
    }
}
```

Comment: are you sure the English version is en_US, since this check fails?

Comment: yes I am sure en_US

Comment: I am also looking for a solution to this issue. The problem with 'woocommerce_thankyou' is that the page is always the English one, since WooCommerce redirects from the Thank You English page after the payment is done.